# Field maps and Survey123

Tags: arcgis-survey123, arcgis-field-maps

Can you use field maps to drop a point location and then it opens Survey123 to fill out the form?

From memory you can do this with collector (drop a point in collector) and it links to Survey123 so you can fill out the survey via a global id.

Just for our mobile team it seems so much easier from them to actually drop the point in field maps/navigate and fill out the form in Survey123. (Noticed field maps inputs some of Survey123 forms but does not have the same functionality)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this through URL parameters in the popup for the points in Field Maps. The feature service should have a GUID or other unique identifier to tie it to a particular survey submission. Users would add a point in Field Maps, then click a link in the popup to open a form in Survey123. Esri's reference for integrating Survey123 with other applications is [here](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/survey123/reference/integratewithotherapps.htm), but essentially, you'll construct a URL like this to open an associated survey form from the popup:

[https://survey123.arcgis.app?itemID=[SURVEY_ID]&field:feature_id={feature_id}](https://survey123.arcgis.app?itemID=%5BSURVEY_ID%5D&field:feature_id=%7Bfeature_id%7D)

I believe you could also build the Survey123 form off the same feature service and use "action=edit" and a query parameter in the URL if you didn't want two separate services. That would depend on the feature existing in the service when they open the link though, so it wouldn't work offline.